# Native join query disable Hibernate NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I want to join some tables with a native query in spring boot.
Query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM employee AS e 
INNER JOIN c ON e.id = c.employee_id 
INNER JOIN b ON c.arw_id = b.arw_id 
INNER JOIN a ON b.ap_id = a.id
```

Now with this I get a Hibernate NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException on `[id]` and `[arw_id]`. I can fix the second one with the `using` annotation, but the `id` of the tables is the entity and I really don't want to change their names...

Any suggestions or is it a Hibernate Bug?

Cheers,
Nicklas

EDIT: For clarification: The first error message I got was this `Encountered a duplicated sql alias [arw_id] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query; nested exception is org.hibernate.loader.custom.NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasExce[...]`.
Then I changed my query to this:

```
SELECT * FROM employee AS e 
INNER JOIN c ON e.id = c.employee_id 
INNER JOIN b ON USING (arw_id) 
INNER JOIN a ON b.ap_id = a.id
```

and got the following error:
`Encountered a duplicated sql alias [id] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query; nested exception is org.hibernate.loader.custom.NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasExce[...]`

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want all the columns from `employee`,`c`,`b`, and `a`?
What are you casting your result into?

If you are casting it to your `Employee` class, just use

```
SELECT e.* FROM employee AS e 
INNER JOIN c ON e.id = c.employee_id 
INNER JOIN b ON c.arw_id = b.arw_id 
INNER JOIN a ON b.ap_id = a.id
```

What makes you so sure that you are getting the error because of `id` and `arw_id`?
They are different fields and they should not give you the error you are mentioning. Or this is most likely because you have the same column names in your `c` or `b` or `a`
In this case, your column names become ambiguous.

It would be much more clear if you could show us a piece of code that you are using this query with

*EDIT*
As I see your edit, all you are doing is making the use of `USING` instead of `ON`. This means you  share your `arw_id` common between two table and this will eliminate double occurence of `arw_id` from your resultset.
If this is the same case with your id, why don't you do the same to your `id`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, I could use `e.*` but that doesn't change the error. Take a look at the edit I just wrote.

Comment: Answer edited as per your question edit

Comment: Because these are two different joins and you can only use `USING` if the two keys you want to join are actually named the same way. Just like I did with `arw_id`, but can not use `USING` with keys `id` and `employee_id` .